# What does NeedsCleaning mean in output of "wmic diskdrive get NeedsCleaning"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, troubleshooting

Does it mean that I should run a CHKDSK (this is on Windows 7) or something else?

Adding more context to the question: I was exploring WMI (Window Management Instrumentation) commands at the CMD prompt, using the form:

cmd /?

to read the help.

While doing that, I tried the above command shown in title of my question.

And it showed output "NeedsCleaning" for a disk I ran it on.

I was a bit worried because I thought it might indicate a disk is about to fail, since I have already observed higher levels of disk LED being on for that particular disk (partition, really), indicating that it is more active than earlier.

Comment: Some context to this question would help. My understanding is that "NeedsCleaning" relates to tape drives. Is that what you are inquiring about?

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Good point. No, disk drives. Have a look at my edited question which provides more context.

Answer (score 1):

[`Win32_DiskDrive` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says about the `NeedsCleaning` property:

> **NeedsCleaning**
>
> Data type: **boolean**
>  Access type: *Read-only*
>
> If **True**, the media access device needs cleaning. Whether manual or
>   automatic cleaning is possible is indicated in the Capabilities
>   property.
>
> This property is inherited from [CIM_MediaAccessDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387901(v=vs.85).aspx).

On the other hand, you could find `VolumeDirty` property in [`Win32_LogicalDisk` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> **VolumeDirty**
>
> Data type: **boolean**
>  Access type: *Read-only*
>  Qualifiers:
>   **[MappingStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393650(v=vs.85).aspx)** ("`FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_DIRTY`")
>
> If **True**, the disk ***requires* [ChkDsk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384913(v=vs.85).aspx) *to be run at the next
>   restart***. This property is only applicable to those instances of
>   logical disk that represent a physical disk in the machine. It is not
>   applicable to mapped logical drives.

**Examples**:

```
==> wmic diskdrive get Capabilities,CapabilityDescriptions,DeviceID,NeedsCleaning
Capabilities  CapabilityDescriptions                 DeviceID            NeedsCleaning
{3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1        
{3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0        


==> wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID,DriveType,FileSystem,VolumeDirty
DeviceID  DriveType  FileSystem  VolumeDirty
C:        3          NTFS
D:        3          NTFS
E:        5          UDF         FALSE
P:        4          NTFS

==>
```

Comment: @JoseZ. Thanks for your reply. Here is some output from the commands you suggested; I will read up on the links you gave.   

wmic diskdrive get Capabilities,CapabilityDescriptions,DeviceID,NeedsCleaning  
{3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}   
 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  

wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID,DriveType,FileSystem,VolumeDirty  

DeviceID  DriveType  FileSystem  VolumeDirty  
C:        3          NTFS  
D:        3          NTFS  
F:        5  
H:        3          NTFS
Sorry for the bad formatting, i.e. joined lines. I tried two spaces at end of each line.

Comment: ... (per what I remembered of Markdown syntax), but that did not work to format the lines properly. Will have to read up on SO text formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

> I was a bit worried because I thought it might indicate a disk is about to fail, since I have already observed higher levels of disk LED being on for that particular disk (partition, really), indicating that it is more active than earlier.

I believe these two things (the command output and your observations/concerns) are extremely unlikely to be related.

[Tape drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive), which are often used for storing large amounts of archival data, [need cleaning](http://www.tandbergdata.com/knowledge-base/index.cfm/do-i-need-to-clean-my-tape-drive/) from time to time to maintain good operation. As part of its support for tape drives, `wmic` has options for [tape drive management](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm). Furthermore, this [Microsoft Technet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/) listing "useful WMIC queries" shows `NeedsCleaning` as one of the useful `get` commands for tape drives (the need for cleaning is often monitored/signaled by the tape drive itself).

However, in your case, it seems very likely you are getting a nonsense answer (you are getting the property name `NeedsCleaning` back, but likely an empty list of values for each drive).

**Rationale**

To support this supposition, running `wmic diskdrive get Capabilities, CapabilityDescriptions, NeedsCleaning` on my system (without tape drives) returned:

```
Capabilities  CapabilityDescriptions                                             NeedsCleaning  
{3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}                                              
{3, 4, 7}     {"Random Access", "Supports Writing", "Supports Removable Media"}                  
{3, 4, 7}     {"Random Access", "Supports Writing", "Supports Removable Media"}                   
{3, 4, 7}     {"Random Access", "Supports Writing", "Supports Removable Media"}                   
{3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}
```

Note the lack of any "manual or automatic cleaning" capabilities or any `NeedsCleaning` value. As mentioned in the [official Win32_DiskDrive class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx), `NeedsCleaning` seems to be an inherited `wmic` property (`wmic diskdrive get /?`), regardless of whether or not it might be useful.